# How do I change the size of a picturebox when the app is run

Tags: c#, windows, resize, picturebox

I wrote a windows application, and I have a PictureBox on my form.  Now, when I run my app, I want to give the resizing ability to my picture box in run time.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the picture box in a container that allows resizing (for example, the split container, or a separate window) and dock to fill.

Comment: i use split container,but i can't change the length,why??